# No save button in Calendar on iPhone

Tags: ios, calendar

When I add an event to my calendar on my iPhone 5s, there is *no* "Save" button, so nothing gets saved to my calendar!
I can set everything but I can't save anything.

Answer (score 2):

There should be an Add button in the top-right corner. It's called "Done" when you are editing an existing event. Those will save your changes and return you to the previous view.

Comment: Thank you for your time - so I touched the "add" and it did return. I went ahead to the day I added the event to and it did not show. Should I not be able to see it if I scroll ahead? so I'm not yet sure if it's there.

Comment: Make sure the calendar you add the event to is being displayed. In the calendar view, tap the "Calendars" button on the center bottom